# How to launch FsUnit tests on Linux/Mac

Tags: f#

I have installed FsUnit

```
» nuget install fsunit
Attempting to resolve dependency 'NUnit (≥ 2.6.3)'.
Installing 'NUnit 2.6.3'.
Successfully installed 'NUnit 2.6.3'.
Installing 'FsUnit 1.3.0.1'.
Successfully installed 'FsUnit 1.3.0.1'.
```

I have created simple unit test:

```
module Tests

open NUnit.Framework
open FsUnit

[<Test>]
let ``simple test`` () =
  1 |> should equal 1
```

Here is I am launching my test:

```
» fsharpc -r NUnit.2.6.3/lib/nunit.framework.dll -r FsUnit.1.3.0.1/Lib/Net40/FsUnit.NUnit.dll 01_binomial_tests.fs
F# Compiler for F# 3.1 (Open Source Edition)
Freely distributed under the Apache 2.0 Open Source License

/Users/demas/development/book_exericses/fsharp_deep_dive/01_binomial_tests.fs(7,1): warning FS0988: Main module of program is empty: nothing will happen when it is run
```

It was compiled fine but I don't know how to launch the tests without VS

**Update**

I have tried to use `NUnit.Runners`:

```
> nuget install NUnit.Runners
> fsharpc -r NUnit.2.6.3/lib/nunit.framework.dll -r FsUnit.1.3.0.1/Lib/Net40/FsUnit.NUnit.dll --target:library  01_binomial_tests.fs
> mono NUnit.Runners.2.6.4/tools/nunit-console.exe 01_binomial_tests.dll
NUnit-Console version 2.6.4.14350
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment -
   OS Version: Unix 14.4.0.0
  CLR Version: 2.0.50727.1433 ( Mono 3.5 ( 3.10.0 ((detached/92c4884 Thu Nov 13 23:27:38 EST 2014) ) )

ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single
Execution Runtime: mono-3.5
Could not load file or assembly '01_binomial_tests, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: as to your update: to me it looks as if it just cannot a dependency - it might be really hard to solve from afar - you should probably call it from the `/bin/debug` (or whatever) directory (usually most dependencies get copied there)

Comment: Thanks. It helps me. I have copied FsUnit and NUnit dll's to program's folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

- Add dependency on `NUnit.Runners` NuGet package, which comes with a stand-alone runner
- Use Xamarin Studio, which seems to have [Unit Tests panel](http://dvmorris.com/unit-testing-with-nunit-and-xamarin/) for running tests
- Use [FAKE](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/) which is a nice F# build tool that can run unit tests

I personally use FAKE because it nicely automates everything. To do that, you need to put something like this in your FAKE `build.fsx` script:

```
Target "Test" (fun _ ->
    !! "/tests*.dll |> NUnit (fun p ->
        {p with
           DisableShadowCopy = true;
           OutputFile = testDir + "TestResults.xml" })
)
```

You'll need dependencies on `FAKE` and `NUnit.Runners` and then FAKE should also find the runner automatically (so you do not have to set it explicitly in your build script).

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have tried to use NUnit.Runners, but get the error message. I have updated my question. Will be appreciate for your help.